# How to avoid the display of gmap favs in embedded maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-embed

How to avoid the displaying of my personal "favs" (the stars that represent my favourite location) in an embedded gmap?
How to avoid to display stars without log-out to my gmap account?
Thanks, Fabio

Comment: Not sure it's an option, you might have to use the [Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) instead

Comment: I try to add the API key. It doesn't change. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Map styles](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) allow you to customize the presentation of the standard Google base map, by changing the visual display of elements such as roads, parks, and built-up areas.

**Example**

Hide *points of interest* feature:

```
var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: berlin
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    map.set('styles', [
        {
            featureType: 'poi',
            elementType: 'all',
            stylers: [
              { visibility: 'off' }
            ]
        }
    ]);
```

You should also try out the [Styled Maps Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html), which allows you to easily experiment with styles, and which creates a style array that you can copy and paste into your code.

**References**

- [Customizing Google Maps: Styling the Base Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/styling-the-base-map)

Comment: Many thanks, point of interests disappear but "stars" of my personal locations remain (if I am logged-in). I would like to make "stars" invisible. Best Regards.

Comment: Fabio, in that case could you please try to specify `'administrative'` instead of `'poi'` for `featureType`?

Comment: Thanks Vadim, even with _administrative_ in "featureType" the personal favs (the stars) are displayed.
We need to discover how to avoid to pass the user-parameters to the embedded map.
Thanks.